# Change the background color of an <option> with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dropdown

So, I know this seems a simple question but it's breaking my mind.

I have a select menu

```
<select class="form-control" id="MYID">
<option value="">Selecione...</option>
<option selected="selected" value="1296">OPTION 1</option>
<option value="2313">OPTION 2</option>
<option value="-3">ADD NEW...</option>
</select>
```

That options value = -3 was added by the controller, so I can't edit with CSS. I wanted to put that option in a different background, using JS.
So I tried getting the ID and then the value and then change the color

```
var option = $('#MYID').val("-3");
option.style.color = "red";
```

I get: Cannot set property 'color' of undefined

I only found answers to "change color to selected option" and that is not what I want.

That option appears in others dropdowns of the software and the value is always the same, so if there was a more general way to do it it would be awesome.

Comment: Please _show us_ what you tried.

Comment: @CBroe, I didn't try much cause I'm getting trouble understanding how to get to the option. But I edited my question. 
var option = $('#MYID').val("-3");
option.style.color = "red";

Comment: `$('#MYID').val("-3")` does not get you the option element, it just _sets_ the option with that value as the selected one for the select element. If you want to get the option element, based on its value, then your first research keyword is _attribute selector_.

Comment: THANK YOU! I can do it in a general way using option[value="-3"] {
  background-color: red;
}

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to @CBroe in the comments I found a way that is the best for me cause it's general.

Selects all  elements with a value="-3" attribute:

```
option[value="-3"] {
  background-color: red;
}
```